# Oxwall - Email Notifications

Tags: php, email-notifications, oxwall

I installed the "Email Notifications" extension on Oxwall, but I didn't receive any emails. I want the user to receive Email notification no matter if he saw the notification on web site.

In other words: If some comment on my post, can I immediately receive email notification?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Its possible in the latest version of Oxwall.

Check your oxwall cron is installed.

Answer (score 0):

You must change the option for users. The default out of the box is to send the notifications if they aren't active for a 2 days. This needs to be set to "immediately" for the notifications to go out like you want.